# Google Closure Compiler Output Hosting?

Tags: time, hosting, google-closure-compiler

How long does Google Closure Compiler https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/ retain the generated output? Could I use this link in production?

`https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/code/alphanumericalstring/default.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui?csw=1) for this service the file is retained for 1 hour:

> For your convenience, the Closure Compiler service hosts the output file default.js on its servers for one hour. You can access the URL of the output file by copying the location of the link that's provided above the output pane, where it says The code may also be accessed at {filename}. If you make any changes to the original JavaScript code and re-optimize it during that hour, Closure Compiler service overwrites the output file with the new results as long as you leave the @output_file_name parameter unchanged at the top of the input field. You can use this feature as a quick way to test your compiled code by linking directly to the file from your test application. Do not link to it from production servers.